# Specific date format from date string in java

Tags: java, string, format

I have a date string which is

```
"20120514045300.0Z"
```

I'm trying to figure out how to convert this to the following format

```
"2012-05-14-T045300.0Z"
```

How do you suggest that I should solve it?

Comment: check guide for SimpleDateFormat and how to work with it.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of diving into hard-to-read string manipulation code, you should parse the date into a decent representation and from that representation format the output. If possible, I would recommend you to stick with some existing API.

Here's a solution based on `SimpleDateFormat`. (It hardcodes the `0Z` part though.)

```
String input = "20120514045300.0Z";

DateFormat inputDF  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss'.0Z'");
DateFormat outputDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'-T'HHmmss.'0Z'");

Date date = inputDF.parse(input);
String output = outputDF.format(date);

System.out.println(output);  // Prints 2012-05-14-T045300.0Z as expected.
```

(Adapted from here: [How to get Date part from given String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601321/how-to-get-date-part-from-given-string/10601392#10601392).)

Comment: I think you are missing a dash, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmss.'0Z'` should be `yyyy-MM-dd'-T'HHmmss.'0Z'`. Since the way you did it will print `2012-05-14T045300.0Z` and not `2012-05-14-T045300.0Z`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the date and them format it to desirable form. Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to do it. You can also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597083/illegal-pattern-character-t-when-parsing-a-date-string-to-java-date) question for more details.

Comment: @Quoi: It's not a *good* answer (compared with aioobe's) but I think it *is* an answer.

Comment: I assume we are not here to just provide code for resolving a problem. I have provided a link to a class which usage is sufficient to solve the problem if one put some effort into learning. Providing the working code gives nothing in point of learning. Though, we can migrate this dicussion to meta.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to use a `DateFormat` for something as simple as this. You know what the format of the original date string is and you don't need a `Date` object, you want a `String`. So simply transform it directly into a `String` (without creating an intermediary `Date` object) as follows:

```
String s = "20120514045300.0Z";
String formatted = s.substring(0, 4) + '-' + s.substring(4, 6) + '-' + s.substring(6, 8) + "-T" + s.substring(8);
```

You can even use `StringBuilder` as follows (although this is a bit inefficient due to array copying):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
sb.insert(4, '-').insert(7,'-').insert(10,"-T");
String formatted = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to reformat the string, you could use something like so:

```
String str = "20120514045300.0Z";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(.+)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.matches())
{
    String newStr = m.group(1) + "-" + m.group(2) + "-" + m.group(3) + "-T" + m.group(4);
    System.out.println(newStr);
}
```